# Can't make fa-icon to work in an Angular sub-module

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I need to create a very simple static application based on Angular 12 ("static" means it doesn't use AJAX) and to display some FontAwesome icons. I decided to [upload the repository earlier](https://github.com/Zighinetto/privacy-app-demo)

I did `ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` and chose all icon packs. Then I wanted to create a privacy policy page using Angular routing and components. I had done this before, but I am not being successful here.

I added `FontAwesomeModule` to the app module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    FontAwesomeModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(fa: FaIconLibrary, faConfig: FaConfig) {
    fa.addIconPacks(fab, fas, far);
    faConfig.fixedWidth = true;
  }
}
```

Then the `ComponentsModule` imports the `PagesModule`. I even tried to import and export at the same time the `FontAwesomeModule`.

Nothing.

If you look at the [template](https://github.com/Zighinetto/privacy-app-demo/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html#L28) I can use the `<fa-icon [icon]="['fab','github']"></fa-icon>` syntax. But in the
[privacy policy page](https://github.com/Zighinetto/privacy-app-demo/blob/master/src/app/pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component.html#L3), no matter what, I always get the same error

```
Error: src/app/pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component.html:3:5 - error NG8001: 'fa-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3     <fa-icon fixedWidth="true" [icon]="warning"></fa-icon>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './privacy-policy.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component PrivacyPolicyComponent.


Error: src/app/pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component.html:3:32 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'.
1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'icon' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

3     <fa-icon fixedWidth="true" [icon]="warning"></fa-icon>
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './privacy-policy.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component PrivacyPolicyComponent.
```

I imported the `FontAwesomeModule` in the application's main module according to FA instructions. But it only works on the main page and not in pages contained in a submodule.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you imported PrivacyPolicyComponent in AppModule or at that module where you are using it

Comment: I have `declare`d it. If I comment the `fa-icon` out, the draft page of the privacy policy is displayed

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sub-module that's hosting the PrivacyPolicyComponent, then you need to import FontAwesomeModule in that sub-module.

For instance, if you have a 'pagesModule' that's hosting the PrivacyPolicyComponent, then add FontAwesomeModule in that module instead of the app.module.